# Cannot find c:\Users\qt\work\install\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib when compiling QtWebEngine examples

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtwebengine, qt5.6

I downloaded Qt5.6 VS2013 32bit and try to run the official example of QtWebEngine.
I just followed the instruction but
When linking it gives out an error of

```
LNK1104 file not found c:\Users\qt\work\install\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib.
```

However, I have no idea of where this path c:\Users\qt\work\install\lib\ comes from.
I did text search in all directories of example folder and no hits other than generated files(makefiles and pdbs).

I also checked system environment variables but no hits.
Furthermore, I checked Qt Creator'r Projects panel and its Build Environment and still no hits.

Did I miss something?

P.S. this error was given out by linking DemoBrowser example of QtWebEngineWidgets pro

Comment: May it be a bug in the Qt distribution itself?

Answer (score 0):

The link is generated by qmake when it generates the build scrip from the qt project file (*.pro). It is based from the qmake application path that is generaly installed together with the libraries (check you qt kit setup to change it if needed: Jst browse to qmake.exe application).
Then try regenerate the build script. It should fix the issue.

You may also have issue with installation not being in debug mode; you are trying to use `Qt5Widgetsd.lib` library instead of the non-debug one `Qt5Widgets.lib`